# Is there a way when application starts immediately method ExecuteEvery5Min gets execute and then through timer every 5 minute?

Tags: c#

I'm using a `Timer` which invoke some piece of code `ExecuteEvery5Min` every 5 minute.

Now I start console application and I have to wait for 5 minutes and then code `ExecuteEvery5Min` is execute and then after every 5 minutes....

Is there a way when application starts and immediately code `ExecuteEvery5Min` execute and then through timer every 5 minute?

```
using (UtilityClass utilityClass = new UtilityClass()) // To dispose after the use
        {
            while (true) { }
        }


public class UtilityClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer;

    public UtilityClass()
    {
        _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds)
        {
            Enabled = true
        };

        _Timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            ExecuteEvery5Min();
        };
    }

    private void ExecuteEvery5Min()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Every 5 minute at {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true) { }` is brutal. Please change it to something like `while (true) Thread.Sleep(10);` 

Comment: Yes, here just to tell in simple code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply call the code in the constructor (to have it immediately) on top of in the timer?

```
    _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds)
    {
        Enabled = true
    };

    // add this
    ExecuteEvery5Min();

    _Timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        ExecuteEvery5Min();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you could use the `System.Threading.Timer` instead, it has the following constructor:

```
public Timer (System.Threading.TimerCallback callback, object state, int dueTime, int period);
```

Quoting from the below link:

> **dueTime** Int32 The amount of time to delay before callback is invoked,
>   in milliseconds. Specify Infinite to prevent the timer from starting.
>   Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.
>
> **period** Int32 The time interval between invocations of callback, in
>   milliseconds. Specify Infinite to disable periodic signaling.

PS: It's callback-based, instead of event-based like the one you're using now.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) uses a [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) [`internally`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs.html#897683f27faba082). It is the same thing with a more friendly interface.